# How would I modify the page just before it renders in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember.js-view

I'd like to add a class to a specific HTML element based on whether it's the selected one at the time.  It's selected based on the current page.

For some reason, I'm having a hard time finding how to do that.

Is there a hook or an event that I should look for?

Here's my route:

```
App.OptionRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function(params) {
        return this.modelFor('simpleSearch')[params.question_id];
    },

    actions: {
        select: function(optionId) {
            console.log("Option Route");
            console.log(optionId);
        }
    }
});
```

How would I grab `params.question_id` and then use that to add the class to my element?

Should this be done in the class for the view instead?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Ember you should avoid programmatically modifying the DOM. If you need to reference the current question_id from within a class element, you should use [bind-attr](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#toc_code-bind-attr-code-and-the-code-class-code-attribute) to bind the question_id to the class from your handlebars template.

Comment: Ah - Thank you.  I did just find bind-attr.  I have come across another problem, though, and I think I might open a new question for it.  The child template of the page is based on a URL parameter.  But the element that I'd like to bind a class to is on the parent template, but also based on that same URL parameter that the child template is.  I don't know how to access the URL parameter from within the parent route/controller/view.